# Easier menu generation depended on session

Tags: php, php-generators

I am making a menu for website language and it works but i think the way i am doing it is not the best way in case i add more languages in future. 
Maybe someone can show a better example.
Here is a piece of what i've got.

```
if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    if ($lang == "en") {
        echo '<li class="">EN 
              <ul>
              <li class="submenu">RU</li>
              <li class="submenu">ES</li>
              <li class="submenu">GR</li>
              <li class="submenu">DE</li>
              </ul>
              </li>';
    }
    if ($lang == "de") {
        echo '<li class="">DE 
              <ul>
              <li class="submenu">RU</li>
              <li class="submenu">ES</li>
              <li class="submenu">GR</li>
              <li class="submenu">EN</li>
              </ul>
              </li>';
    }
    // and so on for every language.. 
}
```

Probably would be better doing some array and than foreach function, but i have no idea how to do that x,x way too confusing

Comment: You should store the languages in a database, then display as many options as languages in the database.

Comment: Well languages option is an addition, i dont really want to add it to database. 
Maybe i can do it by array somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an array, it's possible to create a function, this function will get the language as parameter and display the options according to it :

```
<?php

function display ( $lang )
{ $arr = array( "en" => array( "RU","ES","GR","DE" ),
                "de" => array( "RU","ES","GR","DE" )
              );
  echo '<li class="">' .
       '<ul>';
  foreach ( $arr[ $lang ] as $item ) // DISPLAY THE OPTIONS.
    echo '<li class="submenu">' . $item . '</li>';
  echo '</ul>
        </li>';
}

display( "en" ); // DISPLAY OPTIONS FOR "EN".
display( "de" ); // DISPLAY OPTIONS FOR "DE".

?>
```

In the future, you may add more languages to the array.

To test it, copy-paste previous code in a file, save it as PHP and open it in your browser.

Comment: Yes, you can call the function as `display( $_SESSION['lang'] );`.

Comment: Thats good, the only issue with it right now is we need to remove the selected language from submenu while generating

Comment: `echo '<li class="">' . $lang .` => `echo '<li class="">' .`. Wait, but you are displaying the language in your example : EN, DE.

Comment: ahh all ok i just remove it from array

Comment: Nooo, it MUST be in the array, it's the index. Anyway, change it as you need it.

Comment: "de" => array( "RU","ES","GR","DE" ) i just remove the , "DE" and its fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should be @ help, i defined an array for languages and anytime you need to add a language, you just added there.

```
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
$languages = array ("de" => "DE", "ru" => "RU", "en" => "EN");

foreach ($languages as $key=>$val) 
    if ($lang == $key) 
    {
        unset($languages[$key]);
        $main_lang = $val;
        }

echo "
<li class=\"\">$main_lang //main button
   <ul> // sub menu";
foreach ($languages as $language)
    echo "<li class=\"submenu\">$language</li>";
echo "
   </ul>
</li>";
```

Comment: just put all in a test.php file, define $lang="en"; on top, and load the file, and you should see the result, it's working